# Is there a way to run rsync over a USB / serial connection through a terminal program.

Tags: linux, sync, rsync, serial

I want to keep two directories in sync between my laptop (Ubuntu) and my PocketCHIP (Debian) which connects over USB serial.

I use cu to log in to the PocketCHIP, but is there a way to rsync between them (without being on a network)

Answer (score 3):

Set up a PPP connection – configure `pppd` on both sides to attach to the serial device (Google keyword "null modem pppd"). You'll get a ppp0 interface which supports TCP/IP, just like with old-school dial up modems.

On the 'server' side, it should be possible to create a special user account and set its shell to pppd; that way you'll still have a regular login prompt via cu. The client will need to use a "chat script" to log in. (This is probably similar to how UUCP is used.)

Comment: Thanks. I'm sure this is a good answer, but even after googling around the subject I'm still too ignorant of this level to make much sense of it. Do you know any simple / beginner tutorials for this?

Comment: http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/PPP-HOWTO/direct.html might be a good start.